# C# MySql.Data INSERT INTO error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I use the MySql.Data in c# for a mysql connection. On another program it worked but currently i'm hanging on the INSERT INTO command.

I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES ('PGJWZBPOWTRPUTKY')' at line 1
```

With this code:

```
MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO jt_teamsync (key) VALUES ('" + TeamSyncKey + "')";
        Connection.Open();
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
        Connection.Close();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: That error from what I am looking at pretty much if not tells you what the direct error is.. also what is `key` is that a field name..if so the why not `Alias` the table name `"INSERT INTO jt_teamsync J (j.key) VALUES ('" + TeamSyncKey + "')";` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KEY` is a reserved keyword in mysql. It should be escaped using backtick,

```
INSERT INTO jt_teamsync (`key`) VALUES(...)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, your query is very weak. It is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Parameterized the value to avoid from it, eg

```
string content = TeamSyncKey;
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO jt_teamsync (`key`) VALUES (@key)";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", content);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(MySqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tried it with the ' instead of ` before but it won't work though.

Comment: yes because single quotes are for string literals. table names as well as column names are identifiers.